# Unable to install a specific site extension in Azure Web App

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I want to install a site extension to my Web App. Site Extension - Azure Web Apps Disk Usage. However, the problem is that I cannot find the extension in the list of extensions that are shown to me. I have checked the list of extension in the Azure portal as well is the scm site, but there are only a limited set of extensions are shown to me.
[image]

What am I missing here? 
Is there some setting that I am missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the deal: site extensions have moved to nuget.org per [this annoucement](https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements/issues/87). It was up to each extension owner to move their extension from the old gallery.

For this particular extension, here is the issue I had opened to track it: https://github.com/rajkumar-rangaraj/MAWSFileExplorer/issues/5. But the author never picked it up, so it never made it to the new gallery. We can try to ping the author, but in the end it is up to him. I will try to contact him again.

Comment: I talked to the owners and they have now added it to nuget.org.

Comment: You can find the package [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MAWSFileExplorer/) in nuget.org